# Can a single database configured to multiple ports in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic

We have created different ports for a single database and assigned to the "specific" database. Is it allowed / Does it make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely, yes. Multiple ports can be configured and used and bound to the same content database.

Each MarkLogic application server is bound to a port. The application server can be an [HTTP](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/http), [XDBC](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/xdbc), [WEBDAV](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/webdav), or [ODBC](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/odbc).

Each application server is configured with modules and content databases.

You may choose to have multiple application servers that each have the same content database.

A very good example would be if you wanted to have an HTTP server for application/user traffic, an XDBC server used to run CoRB batch processing jobs, and an ODBC server setup for a BI tool, such as [Tableau](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/examples_marklogic.htm) or Power BI; with all of them configured with the same content database.